# Dart Angular2 - bind component boolean with checkbox value

Tags: checkbox, angular, dart

I'd like to know if there is a way to bind a regular checkbox in a template :

```
<input type="checkbox">
```

with a boolean in my component.

Bonus question : Otherwise is there a way to do

```
<input type="checkbox" {{mybool ? 'checked' : ''}}>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="mybool">
```

or

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="mybool">
```

Comment: As simple as that... Thanks